# React component isn't rendering after updating state by useState

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to update an state object **userInfo** which contains an array named **work** which is an array of objects

My Database object **userInfo** looks like this

```
{
"_id":"61a6a1d64707c03465eae052",
"fullName": "Md Nurul Islam",    
"works": 
[
    {
    "isEditing": false,
    "_id": "61a6a1d64707c03465eae053",
    "company": "Amazon Logistics",
    "position": "Sortation Associate",
    "isCurrent": true
    }, 
    {
        "isEditing": false,
        "_id":"61a6a1d64707c03465eae054",
        "company": "The Rani Indian Takeway",
        "position": "Customer Service Assistant",
        "isCurrent": false,
    }
]    
}
```

But I don't want update the database, i just want to update the state **userInfo** in frontend to go editing mood, for this when the user clicks ***edit*** next to work section, the properties ***isEditing*** will be toggled.

Below is my code

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(user);
const workToggleHandler = (work) => 
{
  setUserInfo((prev) => {
  prev.works.map((p) => {
    if (p._id === work._id) {
      p.isEditing = !p.isEditing;
    }
    return p;
  });
  return prev;
});
```

With this code, my state object is updated But my components are not re-rendered

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` returns a new object but you don't do anything with that and just return the old object. Also `p.isEditing = !p.isEditing` mutates the state, which can break rendering new data and is strongly discuraged when working with react state.

Comment: I Have changed my code in this way 

      `setUserInfo({
            ...userInfo,
             works: userInfo.works.map((p) => {
             return p._id === work._id ? { ...p, isEditing: !p.isEditing } : p;
          }),
      }); `

is it gonna avoid mutating state ?

Answer (score 1):

you can put into the `useEffect` when particular state is updated then that effect will call

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  your code will go here
}[userInfo]),
```

Comment: thank you mate , i tried it earlier, but it was not working in that way.

Answer (score 0):

React does not look at the data of the object but rather on the pointer of the object. Since this is not changed (only "prev" is edited, no new object with a new object address), it doesn't not rerender.
A solution would be to copy the object.

```js
let newUserInfo = Object.assign({}, prev);
newUserInfo.works.map((p) => {
    if (p._id === work._id) {
        p.isEditing = !p.isEditing;   
    }
    return p;
});
return newUserInfo;
```

Disclaimer: Maybe a deep copy is necessary....

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my code on **workToggleHandler** function and its working completely as i want.
Below my code

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(user);
const workToggleHandler = (work) => {
setUserInfo({
  ...userInfo,
  works: userInfo.works.map((p) => {
    if (p._id === work._id) {
      p.isEditing = !p.isEditing;
    }
    return p;
  }),
});
};
```